# PHP, convert $_GET elements to HTML entities

Tags: php, get, html-entities

**Edit**: I think `%27` is actually the wrong kind of quote. I am still stuck though, I cannot find a PHP function that does the conversion I want.

**Edit (again)**: I found a solution where I stick `%26rsquo%3bs` into the URL and it turns into `&rsquo;`. It works so I posted it as an answer below but I'd still be interested in knowing how it'd be done with PHP functions.

I'm working on a website that uses a PHP tree as if it were a directory. For example, if someone types `index.php?foo=visual programming` (or `index.php?foo=visual%20programming`) then the website opens the item "Visual Programming" (I'm using `strtolower()`).

Another working example would be `index.php?foo=visual programming&bar=animated path finder` which opens "Animated Path Finder", a child of "Visual Programming".

The problem is that some of the items are named things like "Conway`&rsquo;`s Game of Life" which uses a HTML entity. My guess of what someone should type to open this would be `index.php?foo=visual%20programming&bar=conway%27s%20game%20of%20life`. The problem is that `'` is not `===` to `&rsquo;`.

What do I need to do to make this work? Here is my code that selects an item based on `$_GET` (the PHP is inside of `<script type="text/javascript">`):

```
<?php
    function echoActiveDirectory($inTree) {
        // Compare $_GET with PhpTree
        $itemId = 0;
        foreach ($_GET as $name) {
            if ($inTree->children !== null) {
                foreach ($inTree->children as $child) {
                    if (strtolower($child->title) === strtolower($name)) {
                        $itemId = $child->id;
                        $inTree = $child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Set jsItems[$itemId].selected(), it will be 0 if nothing was found
        echo "\t\tjsItems[".$itemId."].selected();\n";
    }
    echo "// Results of PHP echoActiveDirectory(\$root)\n";
    echoActiveDirectory($root);
?>
```

The website is a work in progress, but it can be tested here to see `$_GET` working: http://alexsimes.com/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex code `%27` (39 decimal) will never translate to `&rsquo;`, since it is a completely different entity ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)). It *could* be translated to `&apos;`, but PHP doesn't do that (although I don't know the reason for that).

**Edit**

While there is no standard for URL-encoding multibyte character sets, PHP will treat a string as just a set of bytes, and if those match an UTF-8 sequence, it will work:

`php -r 'echo htmlentities(urldecode("%E2%80%99"), ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML401);'`

should output

`&rsquo;`

Comment: I figured that out eventually but the problem is still converting the appropriate URL encoding.

Comment: Ok, got it. I added the info to the post.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain the `%E2%80%99` part and the `-r`?

Comment: `php -r` on the command line just runs the code passed in the string and `%E2%80%99` are just the URL-encoded bytes of the single right quote in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html_entity_encode()` and `html_entity_decode()` PHP functions to convert those characters to html entities or decode them back to desired characters before comparison.

Comment: I've been playing with it and my best guess so far is to do `htmlentities(urldecode(` a get element `), ENT_QUOTES)`. At least it converts `%27` to `&#039;`, but I want `&rsquo;`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function to convert special characters to corresponding html entity. But in your case if data is already stored in db as html entity form, the data from $_GET parameter must be first passed through htmlentities before using it in your query.

Comment: This converts to the wrong form (`&#039` instead of `&apos;` for `%27`). Not sure how to implement this